# Is the Jedi Knol Ven'nari able to use fire based attacks?

Tags: star-wars

The Jedi Master *[Knol Ven'nari](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Knol_Ven%27nari)* was known as the *Fire Eater*, and had pyrokinetic abilities. Was there any mention that she could shoot balls or streams of fire, similar to the firebenders from Avatar: The Last Airbender?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

It is only said the she could *manipulate* fire with the Force.  There is no specific passage I've read mentioning that she could *create* fire using the Force.